# How to undo an edited ms word file after closing

Tags: microsoft-word

Suppose I edited a plain text file in ms word 2010 and saved, then closed. Now i want to undo my editing in the same file. Is there anyway to get back the file in its previous form? please help me.

Comment: Nope. If the data is that precious to you, you should have some sort of revision control on it.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be a downer, but once you close a file, only the Content is saved. Not the history of the document. It depends on whether you keep a backup of this plain text file or not.

Answer (score 0):

### Once you save it, you should assume that it's committed, and you can't undo.

However, if you have enabled Volume Shadow Service (Shadow Copy Service) on the volume in question, you can right-click on the folder where the file is found, select Properties, and look at the PREVIOUS VERSIONS tab, where you can possibly find a copy of the file from before your edit, and copy that back to the "live" folder.

Comment: Ok i enabled VSS and created/ edited a file on desktop then stopped  VSS, now where to find the file backup

Comment: You don't turn off VSS; it should stay running all the time. You can't look at Previous Versions if it's not running.

Comment: You should look at Windows Help for "previous versions"; it will explain how it works.